# How use React without web pack, node, nom etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use React without webpack, node etc.
I want structure each component in separate file, this is what I'm doing:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="root">
      <!-- This div's content will be managed by React. -->
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/demandAnalysis/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
import SimpleButton from './componets/Buttons/SimpleButton.js';

    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Button/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

**SimpleButton.js**

```
class SimpleButton extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <button type="button">Click me!</button>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

But give me this error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I think is caused by the `import`, how can use this structure also without node or web pack?

Comment: You need to transpile `jsx` to `js` before the browser can understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` is an ES6 feature, which is currently not supported by many browsers. That is the reason why `babel` is used to transpile your code into ES5. This is also true for `class`, `extends` and JSX that you are using.

If you do not want to use a transpiler you should use `require` instead of `import` and `React.createClass({ ... })` instead of `class`.

An example of `require` instead of `import`:

`var SimpleButton = require('./componets/Buttons/SimpleButton.js');`

Comment: We have 2017 - it is time for ES6, class and extend keyword …

Comment: Can you have an example of require?

Comment: @Piero added an example ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I Want use import instead, i have imported babel can i import something else to make it working?

Comment: @Piero have you sorted this out? To use import you need not only babel, but also a transpiler - a tool which would convert ES6 syntax to ES5.

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas yes thanks, I have switched to a full react app :)

Comment: @Piero great! Make sure to mark the answer so that others can save time.